# Is there any way to constrain a superview's height to be equal to the max y of its subviews?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I'd like to set up a constraint or multiple constraints that set the height of a view to the max y of it's lowest subview, which is known at design-time. (Essentially so that the view wraps its subviews).
Obviously I can do this in code by modifying the constant of a height constraint, but I don't want to do this because it necessitates knowing about the lowest subview in the code, which I don't think is a clean solution.
So I'd like to do this in IB only.
Thanks!

Comment: 1. Are you sure you mean the max y, not the max height?
2. Do you mean by lowest: the deepest in hierarchy, or the subview with the least y?

Comment: @khalafnt I do mean max y. In the same sense as the function CGRectGetMaxY means it. In other words, the subview with the highest sum: origin.y + size.height.